# Prove that $ T $ is a normal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $ V $ be an finite-dimensional inner product space over $ \mathbb{C} $.

Let $ T : V \to V $ be a linear transformation and assume that for every $ v $, $ \lVert Tv \rVert =\lVert T^*v\rVert$. I want to prove that $ T $ is a normal transformation.

My effort:

Suppose, to the contrary, that $ T $ is not normal and therefore there exists a $ \vec{u} $ such that $ TT^*(\vec{u}) \neq T^*T(\vec{u}) $.

$ \lVert Tv\rVert^2= \langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \langle v, T^*Tv\rangle$

$ \lVert T^*v \rVert^2=\langle T^*v, T^*v\rangle=\langle v, TT^*v\rangle$

which means $ \lVert Tv\rVert^2 - \lVert T^*v \rVert^2==\langle v, (T^*Tv 
-TT^*v) \rangle$

I now want to show that $ T^*Tv- TT^*v \not \perp u $, but I don't really know how? Could you give me a $ \textbf{hint} $?

Comment: $A=T^* T- T T^*$ is self-adjoint, so choose $u$ to be an eigenvector of $A$ and not just any $u$.

Answer (score 1):

From the last equation you have derived you get that the RHS inner product is zero for all $v\in V$.

The hint is the term "Polarisation" to finish your proof,
cf wikipedia or
[math SE's "Polarization identity in Hilbert space"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174427/316749)
if you'd want to stay on this site.

Furthermore, the post
[If $(Tx \mathbin{|} x) = 0$ for all $x$ then $T = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033703/if-tx-mathbin-x-0-for-all-x-then-t-0)
is a seamless sequel of your post.

Comment: My linear algebra course is not in English, and so I am not familiar with the term "Polarization" $ \textbf{ in English } $. Could you, please, direct me to a page where I could read about it?

Comment: @talopl Polarization Identity is a standard result. You can find it in Wikipedia.

Comment: As I see no reaction may I ask  @talopl if this is a satisfactory hint/answer ?

Comment: @Hanno Unfortunately, no. I tried to expand what I got using the Polarization Identity, and yet all I got were messy calculations.

Comment: @talopl I'd propose you *first* get yourself acquainted with the polarisation identity itself, e.g. by going through the given references/links, for which you asked in your first comment. *Secondly*, you will see that it directly applies to your reasoning above as
$0=\lVert Tv\rVert^2 - \lVert T^*v \rVert^2=\langle \,v,\, (T^*T 
-TT^*)v\,\rangle$ for all $v\in V$.